# Variadic logger dispatcher

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am implementing sort of a logging dispatcher, i.e. `int32_t logf(const char *fmt, ...);` which outputs to different logging targets, depending on which options it was compiled with.

The following is a boiled down excerpt.

```
int32_t logf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list    va;
    i32        res;

    va_start(va, fmt);

    res = S_PASS;

#ifdef LOG_UART
    res = Uart_vprintf(fmt, va);
    if (res != S_PASS) goto exit;
#endif /* LOG_UART */

#ifdef LOG_SYS
    res = System_vprintf(fmt, va);
    if (res != S_PASS) goto exit;
#endif /* LOG_SYS */

exit:
    va_end(va);

    return res;
}
```

Now... If no options are given, the logger would (and actually is intended to) be a null-logger. However, do I then still need the calls to `va_start()` and `va_end()` in there?

In other words (ignoring -Wunused-label for a second), is this correct:

```
int32_t logf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list    va;
    i32        res;

    va_start(va, fmt);

    res = S_PASS;

exit:
    va_end(va);

    return res;
}
```

...or this?

```
int32_t logf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    i32        res;

    res = S_PASS;

    return res;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The resulting *empty* function implementation cannot be replaced by a function-style macro like `#define logf(fmt, ...) S_PASS;`.

The existing code base has defined `typedef int32_t(*logFunc)(const char *fmt, ...);` and therefore pointers to logf must be storable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *no* logging was enabled, I would suggest you instead had simply an empty function, or maybe a variadic macro that expands to `S_PASS`.

Perhaps something like

```
#if defined(LOG_UART) || defined(LOG_SYS)
inline int32_t logf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    // Your original code here...
}
#else
# define logf(x, ...) S_PASS
#endif
```

---

The above is if you define the function in your header. If you only have a declaration in your header with the definition in a source file it's almost the same.

Header file:

```
#if defined(LOG_UART) || defined(LOG_SYS)
int32_t logf(const char *fmt, ...);
#else
# define logf(x, ...) S_PASS
#endif
```

Source file:

```
#if defined(LOG_UART) || defined(LOG_SYS)
inline int32_t logf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    // Your original code here...
}
#endif
```

---

After your comment about function pointers, then the best solution is probably to have a inline function function which *only* does `return`S_PASS`:

```
#if defined(LOG_UART) || defined(LOG_SYS)
int32_t logf(const char *fmt, ...);
#else
inline int32_t logf(const char *fmt, ...) { return S_PASS; }
#endif
```

Comment: The variadic macro should expand to `S_PASS` to match the return value of the empty function.

Comment: Yea, that would mostly be the same as the second variant. Yet, is that correct? Can I just declare variadic params to a function and never use va_start and va_end?

Comment: @mch Yes you're correct. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah yea now I see. Sounds pretty good to me. And how would I handle such function-style macro definitions, when I have a header that declares these logging functions?

Comment: @baeda No it's *not* the same as the second variant of your. In your second variant there is still a function call. If using the macro in my answer there's no function call, just a value that the compiler might be able to optimize out if you don't use it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The only issue I am having with this (and sadly I didn't know this up front) is that the code base using this logger is also taking function pointers to it in various places. So replacing the whole thing with a macro is out of the question.

Comment: @baeda Updated my answer. Please update your question with this information as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay fine. That leads me back to the original question: when I declare a function with variadic params, is it then ok to not call va_start and va_end?

Comment: @baeda  Yes it's okay not to "call" the `va` macros.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a moot point because you're shooting yourself in the foot when you propose *only* a variadic function. Your variadic function should always be a wrapper to a `va_list` one:

```
int32_t vlogf(const char *fmt, va_list va);

int32_t logf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int32_t res;
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);

    res = vlogf(fmt, va);

    va_end(va);
}
```

In addition, you're not supposed to use the same `va_list` twice, so if both macros are defined, you need to `va_copy` it:

```
int32_t vlogf(const char *fmt, va_list va)
{
    i32        res;

    res = S_PASS;

#if defined(LOG_UART) && defined(LOG_SYS)

    /*Can't use the same va_list twice: */
    /*If both are defined, need to use va_copy*/
    {
        va_list    va2;
        va_copy(va2, va);

        res = Uart_vprintf(fmt, va);
        if (res != S_PASS) goto exit2;

        res = System_vprintf(fmt, va);
    exit2:
        va_end(va2);
    }
    if (res != S_PASS) goto exit;

#elif defined(LOG_UART)
    res = Uart_vprintf(fmt, va);
    if (res != S_PASS) goto exit;
#elif defined(LOG_SYS)
    res = System_vprintf(fmt, va);
    if (res != S_PASS) goto exit;
#endif /* LOG_SYS */

exit:
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Very useful info about copying the va_list and wrapping in separate vlogf!